# “Denote” or “Denoting”?

Tags: writing, grammar

When I am writing paper, I am often confused with the usage of `Verb` or `Verb-ing`  at the beginning of proof proceed,  for example:

> Denote the following stochastic process 
>   [image: Mathematical formula]

or

> Denoting the following stochastic process
>   [image: Repeat of the same Mathematical formula]

which one is correct?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about English, not about academia (and not specific to academic writing.)

Comment: Do you want me to migrate this to [ell.se]?

Comment: Yes, I donot know how to do it

Comment: Placing these phrases within the context of a complete sentence will make it easier for others to provide a definitive answer to your question.

Comment: @pyobum I updated my question, it's now within a complete sentence.

Comment: Do you intend to mean "Let the left-hand-side symbol be the right-hand-side one."? If this is the case, then I am afraid neither "denote" nor "denoting" is correct. Instead, you should say, for example, "By the left-hand-side symbol we denote the right-hand-side symbol."

Comment: @Chou I would like to change "denote" as "change", it seems okay now?

Comment: @WangyanLi: If this is the case, simply saying, for example, "Let *a* := *b*" suffices.

Comment: I disagree with the close vote. How this question is *unclear*, you tell me.

Comment: In my opinion (I haven't voted to close this answer, by the way), it's unclear because the verb "denote" doesn't make sense to me in the example above. Does it mean that something before the "Denote" line *denotes* equation (36)? Or was the OP trying to mean "Please note this equation"? Or "Let's consider this equation"? Or "Then we arrive at this equation"? Or something else?

Comment: @DamkerngT. Not something before, just following equation (36).

Comment: @WangyanLi If it doesn't refer to anything before the sentence, I'd recommend using "Let's consider" (or simply "Consider:"), or as Chou suggested, "Let".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Denoting the following stochastic process

marks that you are using the process to prove/imply/explain something while

> Denote the following stochastic process

is using the process like a definition, an assessment or a conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

You can test for the correct usage when you write a formal proof by first writing it using "I" or "we." For example:

"I denote the following stochastic process by X." or "We define f(x) to be some function."

Then you can remove the "I" and "we" as you see fit.

Comment: normally, we do not write `I` or `We` at the beginning, even it's the first time.

Answer (score 1):

One way to look at this is to substitute the verb "do."

"Do" is a command. "Do something now!" or "Do not do that."

"Doing" describes ongoing action. "He is doing his homework." "You are doing that wrong."

So, I know nothing about the math being shown in the original question. But I read "Denote" as a command to do something, or to follow the way it is being done. I read "Denoting" as ongoing action, which in this case, seems less correct.

However, consider this example in an academic work about grammar, instead of math:

**Use active voice:**
"I went to the store"

**Using active voice:**
"I went to the store."

The difference is really only in tone:

Are you commanding the reader: "**Do** it this way" and showing an example...

- or -

Are you telling the reader, "Here's an example of **doing** it this way" and showing an example.